# Использование GSM модуля

Tags: железо

Стоит задача: написать программу которая будет через gsm модуль смартфона(программа установленная на телефоне) общаться с антенной/передатчиком, т.е. посылаем сигнал с телефона, антенна принимает, передатчик отправляет его обратно, сигнал с передатчика ловим телефоном. Возможно ли это? Что для этого нужно? И как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит почитать про Hayes-команды и, конкретнее, [Data Transmission Systems and Equipment - Serial Asynchronous Automatic Dialing and Control](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fftp.tiaonline.org%2Ftr-30%2FTR-30.2%2FPublic%2F2005%2520Meetings%2F2005-06%2520Arlington%2FFor%2520Review%2FTIA-602-A.doc&ei=LhN8UpuqLYeK4ATBkoDgDg&usg=AFQjCNFsAxYUmnsH48PSfPkalD2HOMT_bA&sig2=zSQmfnLRSdeFnUz-R_0dgg&bvm=bv.56146854,d.bGE&cad=rjt)

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно. 
Можете конечно попробовать получить права рута и поиграться но я сомневаюсь, что получится у вас как вы говорите "посылать сигнал". 
Мой ответ НИКАК.